# Rails call a controller user-defined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I am working with rails I have a controller name books and has a user defined method in it .I need to call this method so that i can see the output on console.And I dont want to call this method in helpers.

```
def approve
    @user=current_user.users.find params[:id]
    puts '#{@usery}'     
  end
```

Also I Have a link

```
<%= link_to 'approve',users_path,data: { :confirm => 'Are you sure to delete the folder and all of its contents?'} %>
```

.When i click on this link I want to call the above method on it .

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to [define a route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) and call it through that:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
    get :approve, on: :member
end

<%= link_to "Approve", users_approve_path(@user) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Rich suggested that, you can achieve it by `member`. Please note that when you'll create a `member` route in member block

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'approve'
  end
end
```

then you'll get the `params[:id]`. Like

```
def approve
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  puts '#{@user}'     
end
```

and when create a `member` route using `:on` then you'll get `params[:user_id]`. Like

```
def approve
  @user = User.find params[:user_id]
  puts '#{@user}'     
end
```

Path will be same in both cases that is

```
<%= link_to "Approve", users_approve_path(@user) %>
```

Source [Rails - Adding More RESTful Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Happy coding !!!